# Accept only inclusive date in HTML

Tags: html, validation, date

I'm making a simple system and I bumped into this problem. The input field should just accept dates from  ex.(January 13, 2003 to March 18, 2014) otherwise when the submit button is clicked with invalid dates an error message will be shown. Can I do that in HTML?

Comment: Date picker, Validation plugins. But only in JS, pure HTML will not work.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>No, you cannot do that in HTML. HTML has no built-in support for date validation.</strike>

You will have to resort to client-side script or server-side validation.

Surprisingly, yes, [you can do validation with HTML5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Constraint_validation):

```
<input type="date" min="2003-01-13" max="2014-03-18">
```

However, [browser support is lacking](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime), so you are probably better off using client-side script instead.

Comment: Great! Thanks Heinzi. This is fine already. It's just a school activity by the way. :D

Answer (score 0):

Please go to this [link](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) and download this jquery UI datepicker. There is also a view source link on this page and you can see the simple usage of it.

Hopefully it will resolve your problem. You will be able to get date in proper format in your input field moreover you can save it too.